# Attribute error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post' when using multiple submit buttons in my view

Tags: django, post, django-views

I am making a blog app and I need to give multiple buttons to the user when submitting his blog. I am checking which button is set and trying to do the action accordingly but it is not working properly.

Here is my views portion where I am checking which button is set in the POST data but when I click publish it works fine, but if I click save or publish then i get the error
**Attribute error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Post'**

```
@login_required
def blog_form(request,author_id=None,slug=None):

    context_instance=RequestContext(request)

    # This view will have a valid creator_id and slug field if the
    # blog is being edited and in this case the creator and user should be same
    if ( author_id and slug):
        author = User.objects.get(pk=author_id)
        blog = get_object_or_404(Entry, creator = author, slug = slug)
        if blog.creator != request.user:
            raise HttpResponseForbidden()

    # We set the user and created date and make a new object
    else:
        blog = Entry(creator=request.user,created_date=datetime.datetime.now() )

    if request.method == 'POST':

        #if the blog is not published
        if 'save' in request.POST:
            form = EntryForm(request.Post, instance = blog)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

        elif 'publish' in request.POST:
            blog.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            blog.status = 1
            form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance = blog)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render_to_response('blog/blog_view.html', {'blog': blog,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif 'preview' in request.POST: 
            form = EntryForm(request.Post, instance = blog)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render_to_response('blog/blog_view.html', {'blog': blog,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form = EntryForm(instance = blog)

    return render_to_response('blog/blog.html', {'form':form}, context_instance)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exception is telling you everything you need to know - there is no attribute "Post" on request. However, there is request.POST

Comment: Actually I was about to accept the answer but I couldn't as I had to wait for a minute.... Thanks alot

Comment: hey I do not know if I should ask you or not but could you help me in this problem as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421919/how-to-redirect-to-a-different-view-after-processing-a-form-getting-noreversemat I have tried looking for solution but it is not working rather I even used the way they have given the official tutorial and even that is throwing an error